# SQLAlchemy: is it possible to do a select between a certain section of records

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm not looking for the `count` or `filter` expressions, I just want to select from the 5th record to the 10th record, if that makes sense.

I'm working with a very large table but only in small sections at a time, currently each time I need a section I query my entire table and choose my section from the result. But is there a faster way to do it, for example only selecting the records between index 5 and index 10 (My table is indexed by the way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html), it looks as if you could use the [slice](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.slice) filter, or use [limit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.limit) and [offset](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.offset).